# Create a new array containing the index of every occurrance of a target value

Tags: java, arrays, methods, indexing

I'm trying to make a method that creates a new array containing the index of every occurrence of a target value. I have to use 2 loops for this. The first counts how many times the target occurs. Then create the new array, to hold this many indexes. Then the second loop puts the indexes into the new array.

I've written the code below, but it throws `java lang Array Out Of Bound Exception:5`, on the line `result  [ i ]  =  f [ i ] ;`

```
public class FindAll {

    public FindAll() {
        int a[] = {7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7};
        print(findAll(a, 7));
        print(findAll(a, 2));
    }

    public void print(int p[]) {
        System.out.print("{");
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < p.length - 1; ++i) {
            System.out.print(p[i] + ", ");
        }

        System.out.print(p[i]);
        System.out.print("}");
    }

    public int[] findAll(int f[], int target) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; ++i) {
            if (f[i] == target) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        int result[] = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; ++i) {
            if (f[i] == target) {
                result[i] = f[i];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you go through the code execution with a debugger? You would surely find out why it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int result[] = new int[count];
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
{
    if (f[i] == target){
        result[index] = f[i];
        index++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the findAll function with this

```
public int[] findAll(int f[], int target) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; ++i) {
        if (f[i] == target)
            count++;
    }
    if(count == 0) return null;
    int result[] = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0, curr = 0; i < f.length; ++i) {
        if (f[i] == target)
            result[curr++] = i;
            // Here you have to store the index not the value
    }

    return result;
}
```

Add these lines to print method to avoid an exception when the array is null

```
if(p == null || p.length == 0){
    System.out.println("P is null or empty");
    return;
}
```

It will work fine!

Answer (score 0):

The result array you are creating is the size of the number of occurrences of the target, not the size of the original array.

```
 public int[] findAll(int f[], int target)
    {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; ++i)
    {
        if (f[i] == target)
            count++;
    }
    int result[] = new int[count]; // This is the size of number of occurrences of target
    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; ++i) // 'i' will go up to size of original array
    {
        if (f[i] == target)
            result[i] = f[i]; // You are trying to put the element of the original array in to the same index of your result!?
    }

    return result;
}
```

Instead, you need to be adding, for each target element, it's index:

```
int resultIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
    if ( f[i] == target ) {
        result[n] = i;
        n++;
    }
}
```